# Connect php to oracle in parallels plesk panel 11.5

Tags: php, oracle, plesk, parallels

I have a website hosted. The panel that my service provider gave me is the Parallels Plesk 11.5. I need to connect to a remote Oracle database from my server. I know that I need to enable OCI8 in PHP and have Oracle Instant Client installed. I have done this on my windows 7 machine with WAMP and it works fine. The problem is I don't know how to enable OCI8 in the Plesk panel and also how to install Instant Client onto it. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your server OS?

Comment: my server os is Linux x64